# psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory on Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql

When I try to connect to my postgresql database with psql I receive the error message:

```
D:\>psql -U postgres
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5112"?
```

A similar error I get when using createdb:

```
createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
```

next two lines are identical to the psql error.

I can start pgadminIII without problems and access my databases. when I check the properties of the connection it uses port 5432. When using process explorer I see about 5 postgresql processes, though none accessing port 5432. The solutions I found in this forum are about linux/osx platforms, which I am not able to translate into a windows solution.

Could anybody tell what is wrong/what I am doing wrong and suggest a solution?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try giving the port option also when you attempt to connect from psql. psql -p 5432

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it did not work.

Comment: When you use pgAdmin, are you providing hostname?